# AngularJS $http Parameters

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, web-services, hybrid-mobile-app

I am attempting to connect my angularJS app to a web service which i have created. The web service has a switch statement which selects the correct php file depending on the parameters you pass it. In this instance i am looking to pass action, retrieve to the web service. How can make my $http.get pass through parameters which will be read by my switch statement

Call to Webservice

```
function customersController($scope,$http) {
  $http.get("http://10.137.98.144")
  .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});
}
```

WebService

```
switch ($_POST['action'])
            {

            case 'retrieve':
                require "retrieve.php";
                retrieve();
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameters with the url

try this:

```
$http.get("http://10.137.98.144?action=retrieve")
```

in php you can use the param with

```
$param = $_GET('action');
```